# Is there any cloud service which Allows to Store the data but blocks the deletion or manipulation of the same?

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, backup

I am looking for a cloud service where I should be able to store the data but the deletion or manipulation is not allowed by anyone in the firm. The main objective is to store the source code and other data into a storage where no one has write permission over the already present files but atleast one person has permission to store new files. This is to prevent intentional deletion of critical data.

Hope I am clear about my query. I would prefer if it can be done in **AWS** or **Hetzner** cloud.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html), and not grant any users the action "s3:DeleteObject".
Enabling versioning in S3 will mean that you can recover previous versions in the event of accidental deletion. See [S3 IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html).

[AWS CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/welcome.html) is Git code repository. You can store code there, including multiple versions. [Identity and Access Management (IAM)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-iam-identity-based-access-control.html#identity-based-policies-example-4) allows you to deny or allow specific actions on code branches, including pulling, editing or deleting the branch.

You could also use something like [QLDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/what-is.html), which is an immutable ledger.